# Name file based on date and time in Vimwiki

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm not a programmer and I use vim just for taking notes. Now I'm trying to use the [Vimwiki](https://vimwiki.github.io/) plugin.

It allows creating a daily entry. If we type the command `<Leader>w<Leader>w`, the diary-file based on the current date will be created.
I want this file to be named not only by the current date but also by the time of its creation (sort of `2201052359` instead of `2022-01-05`).

I suppose I should write something in the `~/.vimrc` file, but I have no idea what exactly. Should I use the timestamp plugin? If so, how can I use it when creating a vimwiki-diary-file?

Answer (score 0):

Per issue [#1026](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/1026), it is not possible because the format is hardcoded. See [autoload/vimwiki/diary.vim#L89-98](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/e2a6b825de72b308c798620ca6e8c9244329f6a6/autoload/vimwiki/diary.vim#L89-L98).

There is currently an open feature request to allow formatting the date. Subscribe to [#579](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/579) to follow along. I am also interested in a similar feature :).